# How to set browser locale with chromedriver (Python)

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, python, chromedriver

I am trying to set my browser locale by doing the following

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--lang=es')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_location, chrome_options=options)
```

When I browse to [google](http://www.google.com) the site is still displayed in english. 
Am I setting the `"--lang"` option wrong?

Comment: I ran your code. It is working as expected.

Answer (score 13):

**Not Working**

I've tried the `--lang=us` option, as suggested, but also had no success using the code below. My webpages were still being downloaded with my default language (that's not en).

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('lang=en')
# options.add_argument('--lang=en') <- Tried this option as well
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

**Working**

After some research I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/BuhtigithuB/11df8cf8d03bb236985156de204fe7b4) that finally helped me. Their solution is to use the experimental option `intl.accept_languages`, as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {'intl.accept_languages': 'en,en_US'})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

By doing that, pages started to be loaded with the language that I wanted.

Also, Google Chrome [source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc#236) explains that this option will actually set the HTTP header `Accept-Languages` to the given value. What's exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try and convert this to the Python equivalent. Check [**this**](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/TipsAndTricks) link:

For Firefox:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference( "intl.accept_languages", "es" ); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

For Chrome:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--lang=es");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Python equivalent that worked for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
driver_location = "res/chromedriver.exe"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--lang=es')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_location, chrome_options=options)

driver.get("http://google.com")
sleep(3000)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code worked for me both for Chrome and Firefox. This is missing Python code for Firefox:
`firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()`
`firefox_profile.set_preference('intl.accept_languages', 'es')`
`driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=driver_location, firefox_profile=firefox_profile)`

Answer (score 1):

For Perl users here is the magic string:

Selenium::Chrome

my $driver = Selenium::Chrome->new( 'extra_capabilities' => { 'chromeOptions' => { 'prefs' => { 'intl.accept_languages' => 'es' } } });

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happens when I switch Chrome's default language. There are two solutions I can think of - manually add the Accept-Language: es header, or go directly to Google's Spanish version of the homepage - driver.get("http://google.es")

Answer (score 0):

You can add `hl` parameter to your query like https://www.google.com/?hl=es

**Reference:** https://sites.google.com/site/tomihasa/google-language-codes

> you can define the web interface language to be English by adding
> hl=en to the end of the URL and after the change the URL will look
> like this:
> http://www.google.com/search?hl=en